# Show image instead of checked state of checkbox in extjs

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How to show a image (ticked image) instead of the default tick of checkbox when the user checks it?

I tried using `checkedCls` config, in which the image is coming but backside of the checkbox.

```
checkedCls: 'checkedBoxStyle'
```

---

```
 .checkedBoxStyle{
       background-image:url('http://www.chathamhouse.org/sites/default/files/public/images/buttons/tick-icon.png');
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nue7j/4/) to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the image only changes its background position with

```
.x-form-cb-checked {
     background-position: 0 -13px;
}
```

cause the origin image looks like this:

[image]

You should change the whole image here.

I would suggest to change the Base class and force a override

like so:

```
.newBase input{
    background-image:url('../resources/images/checkBox_Tick_Mark.png') !Important;
}
```

And in the config

```
...
baseCls: 'newBase',
...
```

see your **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nue7j/6/)** (The image path is incorrect, but it should show you the trick)

Comment: How to change the whole image? please tell me.

Comment: @Mr_Green Always a pleasure ;)